# How to change all Stripe connected accounts payout setting at once and have the default be manual?

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to change the payouts of all connect accounts on my platform from daily to manual so there are less transaction fees I have to incur. I know by default it is set to daily and if I want to change a user's payout I have to edit their payout schedule in the account balance section from the docs. However, they don't list a way to change the default payout setting to be manual or allow me change the payout settings of every user and I have currently have about 1000 on my platform. Is there a way to have all payout settings change and make manual the default during the onboarding process?

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/add-and-pay-out-guide?integration=without-code#without-code-pay-out-to-user

[image: Stripe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the account, you can set the payout schedule to manual [via the API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create#create_account-settings-payouts-schedule-interval). For existing accounts, you could write a script that iterates through each of your connect account id's and [issues an update account API request to change the payout schedule to manual](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/update#update_account-settings-payouts-schedule-interval).

Comment: thanks man, thought the changes could be made through the dashboard. Will go and update my code.